# Using multi-dimensional array in Perl class

Tags: perl, multidimensional-array

I need to create a multi-dimensional array which will be passed to a class.

Here is sample code where I can reference the array elements outside of the class, but once I create a class and pass the multi-dimensional array, I'm not able to reference it inside of the class.

Output:

**My Array Value = 3**

**Can't use string ("1") as an ARRAY ref while "strict refs" in use at test.pl line 18.**

```
package TestClass;
use strict;

sub new
{
    my $class = shift;
    my $self =
    {
        _array => shift
    };
    bless $self, $class;   
    return $self;
}

sub print
{
    my ($self) = @_;
    print "TestClass variable = " . @{$self->{_array}->[0]}[1] . "\n";
}

my @my_array = ();
push(@my_array, [1,2]);
push(@my_array, [3,4]);

print "My Array Value = " . @{@my_array->[1]}[0] . "\n";

my $class = new TestClass(@my_array);

$class->print;

1;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're passing a list with two elements to your constructor, each element being one of the array refs you built.

I believe you wanted to pass an array reference containing the other two anonymous array references instead:

```
TestClass->new(\@my_array);
```

Your array de-referencing in `@{@my_array->[1]}[0]` is also a little odd. This is something `use warnings;` would've caught.

Comment: Agreed.  `$my_array[1][0]` (or `$self->{_array}[0][1]`) seems easier to read.